# High # of cache faults/sec and transitional faults/sec

Tags: windows-7, audio

The audio on my computer literally drags on, you can hear it 'reverberate' for a second, causing the entire computer to "frameskip" when it gets bad.

I've been checking with perfmon what happens during those "skips", and there are extremely huge spikes in the number of cache faults per second and transitional faults per sec.

This specific red peak represented over 7600 cache faults per second at that moment:
[image]

I did run memtest86+ and the Windows memory diagnostic tool, both returning no errors.

How can I fix this problem or what are my next steps to determine what is wrong?

Comment: run a xperf trace and upload the trace: http://pastebin.com/MVdhhLUD

Comment: @magicandre1981 Did just that, please note that my registry was not edited yet (DisablePagingExecutive was still set to 0). But as it is currently 4:40AM I don't really have the time to reboot and wait for the problems to occur again. If the trace does not suffice, of course I will do it again. [Pagefaulttrace.etl download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33426857/Pagefaulttrace.etl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaMonkey.exe causes several `Demand Zero Page Faults` . this is ok and [doesn't impact performance](http://members.shaw.ca/bsanders/WindowsGeneralWeb/RAMVirtualMemoryPageFileEtc.htm).

> these happen when a process first references newly allocated virtual
>   memory pages.  These do not involve the pagefile at all.  Any process
>   that does frequent memory allocations and de-allocations will
>   experience a significant number of Demand Zero Page Faults. 
>   Processing these events is a very low overhead activity and does not
>   indicate that demand for memory has exceeded the amount of available
>   RAM.  Very high Demand Zero Page Fault rates are quite common for some
>   applications but this by itself has little affect on performance.  The
>   design and implementation of the application affects the rate of
>   Demand Zero Page Faults the application experiences, so this can not
>   be changed by adding RAM or reconfiguring the pagefile.

The DPC issues you see come from USBPORT.SYS:

```
Total = 110173 for module USBPORT.SYS
Elapsed Time, >        0 usecs AND <=        1 usecs,      0, or   0.00%
Elapsed Time, >        1 usecs AND <=        2 usecs,      0, or   0.00%
Elapsed Time, >        2 usecs AND <=        4 usecs,   5712, or   5.18%
Elapsed Time, >        4 usecs AND <=        8 usecs,  11060, or  10.04%
Elapsed Time, >        8 usecs AND <=       16 usecs,    132, or   0.12%
Elapsed Time, >       16 usecs AND <=       32 usecs,      6, or   0.01%
Elapsed Time, >       32 usecs AND <=       64 usecs,     13, or   0.01%
Elapsed Time, >       64 usecs AND <=      128 usecs,    282, or   0.26%
Elapsed Time, >      128 usecs AND <=      256 usecs,   2494, or   2.26%
Elapsed Time, >      256 usecs AND <=      512 usecs,  62236, or  56.49%
Elapsed Time, >      512 usecs AND <=     1024 usecs,  28021, or  25.43%
Elapsed Time, >     1024 usecs AND <=     2048 usecs,    217, or   0.20%
Total,                                                110173
```

Everything over 1024 is bad and causes audio/video glitches. Here you have 217 of them. Put all your logitech devices into different USB ports and see if this improves it (don't use the VIA controller for example). Also make sure the USB ports don't share IRQs with a HDD controller.

Comment: Thanks in advance, I will look through the information at a later date due to me having an exam tomorrow. Will report later when I fixed the problem and edit this comment. (Did change the USB devices though as that is a quickie)

Comment: Nope, problems started again after a short break for Payday 2. Made a small trace, they were worse after the trace though. Really should read into IRQs more. [Pagefaulttrace2.etl](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33426857/Pagefaulttrace2.etl)

Comment: it is better, but you still get USBport.sys DPC spikes.

Comment: Update: Played some rocksmith over another HDD. No problems whatsoever. Problem seems to be tied to the J: harddisk. (Where my steam and rest of the games are installed).

Comment: to which SATA controller is the WDC Caviar Black WD2002FAEX connected?

Comment: That's the J: disk. My main (C:) and the J: disks are connected to the two sata 6G ports. The other two HDDs (D: and E:) are on the 3G ports. (And I believe those are the 2 different sata controllers on my mobo). I will open my case and change some drives around and see what that does. First need to focus on my last exam friday though.

Comment: which motherboard do you use?

Comment: [Asus p7p55d-e](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55DE/)

Comment: ok, this is a Marvel controller. Because you don't use a SSD you can also connect them to the Intel 3G ports. Now disable the Marvel in the BIOS.

Comment: C: is an SSD though, but since its a sata 3G one, moved it to the intel controller regardless, so the 6G harddisk got that 6G controller for himself. (Don't know what a conventional HDD could benefit from the quicker sata connection, but w/e). I also changed all HDDs from IDE mode to AHCI. Well, as far as it goes that DID improve something. Get quite some cache faults regardless, but I haven't noticed anything so far performance wise.
http://i.imgur.com/NGa1zUv.png
Notably less though. Will disable the marvel controller entirely when performance gets hit.

Comment: nice to hear that you fixed the issue.

Comment: Nope, performance got hit again >.<, going to disable the marvell controller in its entirety then tomorrow.

Comment: for christs sake. I still get performance losses while the marvell controller is disabled entirely and everything is on the intel controller.

Comment: capture a new xperf trace

Comment: [Pagefaulttrace3.etl](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33426857/Pagefaulttrace3.etl)

It was still on a bearable level at that point, but it was occurring nonetheless.

Comment: you still have the same USBport.sys DPC issues.

Comment: I reinstalled win7 because I was fed up with it. Not really a solution as I didn't want to have to reinstall everything, but hey, problem is gone at least.

Comment: Latencymon reports ataport.sys to be a problem as well, next to usbport.sys. [Latencymon](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33426857/4bxuj.png) [Pagefaulttrace](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33426857/Pagefaulttrace.etl)

ndis.sys just popped up after all the testing...Apparantly it's something as well.

Comment: ataport.sys = IDE driver. Do you still run drives in IDE mode instead of AHCI? Also USBport.sys is still causing DPCs issues

Comment: I know it's mainly usbport.sys, an no, all drives are in AHCI.

Comment: Literally only my keyboard and mouse are plugged in now (and BT stick on nonactive). Still usbport.sys is having DPC issues.

Comment: to which USB chipset do you connect them now? Install the Debugger from the Win8 SDK and run a tool called USBview.exe. It tells you which USB device is connected to which controller.

Comment: [USBview](http://puu.sh/4gojN.png) 3B3C would be by mouse on. 3B34 the keyboard and BT.

(And btw, I'm on win7, but that doesn't matter much)

Comment: 3B3C and 3B34 = Intel USB. Now look if they share IRQs with SATA controllers where you have drives connected.

Comment: [IRQs](http://puu.sh/4gD6g.png) Hmm on 17, the SATA controller there is shared with HD Audio and 2 ports. 3B42 and 3B4A

However I must note that HD audio is disabled in the BIOS as I use my soundcard, the Asus Xonar DGX on IRQ 19

Comment: disable the VIA controller in the BIOS. also try the Intel AHCI driver.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, I remember what I changed: I deinstalled Logitech Gaming Software (LGS). So that was the culprit. And it makes sense. The problems started to occur around the time I got my Logitech G500 mouse, and I did install it back immediately after I reinstalled Windows.

Comment: ok, so the mouse causes the DPC spikes of the USBport.sys

Comment: I sent logitech support all of my findings. They said it will take them a few days to spit through the data. For now, I can live without LGS.